# Find pairs of files in one directory with a specific pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to find pairs of files with a specific pattern in one directory:

> HU_IP_number_something.bam & HU_inp_number_something.bam
>   NOC_IP_number_something.bam & NOC_inp_number_something.bam

Numbers are 1...N for each pair

I have a solution but it works only for one set of files HU_* or NOC_* in one directory.
How can I improve it to find pairs, when both HU_* and NOC_* are in one directory?

```
for ip in *IP*.bam
   do
        num=$(echo $ip | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
        input=$(find -name *_inp_${num}*.bam)
        echo ip sample: $ip
        echo input sample: $input
   done
```

Examples of files in one directory:

```
HU_inp_1-sorted.bam
HU_IP_1-sorted.bam
NOC_inp_1-sorted.bam
NOC_IP_1-sorted.bam
```

for 1,2,3,...N

Comment: Could you please add a list of actual sample filenames, and the results you'd like to see from that set?

Comment: So .. the pairs are designated by the first part of the filename, i.e. `HU_this` and `HU_that`? There are two ways we can pair these samples, by HU/NOC or by IP/inp.

Comment: Need to pair HU_IP with HU_inp and the same number and need to pair NOC_IP with NOC_inp and the same number. The problem that numbers are the same for both these groups. Need to take prefix and number and find the pair: inp for IP, using unique number and the same prefix.
Sorry, if it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you only want to match HU to HU and NOC to NOC? If so:

If you add a line

```
pre=$(echo $ip | awk -F "_" '{print $1}')
```

then change you input to

```
input=$(find -name $pre_inp_${num}*.bam)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the missing part

Answer (score 1):

The following builds an array, `$a` for each iteration of a for loop.

```
$ for f in *IP*.bam; do s=${f#*_}; a=( *${s} ); declare -p a; done
declare -a a=([0]="HU_IP_number_something.bam" [1]="NOC_IP_number_something.bam")
declare -a a=([0]="HU_IP_number_something.bam" [1]="NOC_IP_number_something.bam")
```

This works steps through all the files you've specified in your filespec, stripping off the first "field" (as denoted by the underscore separator), and using globbing to collect the relevant files in the array.

You can test for the length of the array (`${#a[@]}`) to make sure you have two entries.

If you want to group by the second field instead of the first, you need a little more processing:

```
$ for f in *IP*.bam; do s1=${f%%_*}; s2=${f#*_}; s2=${s2#*_}; a=( ${s1}*${s2} ); declare -p a; done
declare -a a=([0]="HU_IP_number_something.bam" [1]="HU_inp_number_something.bam")
declare -a a=([0]="NOC_IP_number_something.bam" [1]="NOC_inp_number_something.bam")
```

The technique here, using `${var#pattern}` and `${var%pattern}` is called **Parameter Expansion**, and you can find more details about it in the bash man page.  [Here too.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like something useful and very interesting. I will definitely learn it.